# finding $\frac{dz}{dk}$ with differentiation

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Given 
$$
\begin{align*}
y=f(a,b)\\ a=a(u,v) &&b=b(u,v)\\
u=u(r)&&v=v(r)
\end{align*}
$$
Find $\frac{dy}{dr}$? I did it with this method so could somebody assist to confirm the answer?

I have decided to find $\frac{da}{dr}$ and $\frac{db}{dr}$ so

$$
\begin{align*}
\frac{da}{dr} &= \frac{\partial a}{\partial u}\frac{du}{dr} + \frac{\partial a}{\partial v}\frac{dv}{dr}\\\frac{db}{dr} &= \frac{\partial b}{\partial u}\frac{du}{dr} + \frac{\partial b}{\partial v}\frac{dv}{dr}
\end{align*}
$$
Hence
$$
\begin{align*}
\frac{dy}{dr} &= \frac{\partial y}{\partial a}\frac{da}{dr}+\frac{\partial y}{\partial b}\frac{db}{dr}\\
&=\frac{\partial y}{\partial a}\begin{pmatrix}\frac{\partial a}{\partial u}\frac{du}{dr}+ \frac{\partial a}{\partial v}\frac{dv}{dr}\end{pmatrix}+\frac{\partial y}{\partial b}\begin{pmatrix}\frac{\partial b}{\partial u}\frac{du}{dr} + \frac{\partial b}{\partial v}\frac{dv}{dr}\end{pmatrix}\\&=
\frac{\partial y}{\partial a}\frac{\partial a}{\partial u}\frac{du}{dr} + \frac{\partial y}{\partial a}\frac{\partial a}{\partial v}\frac{dv}{dr}+\frac{\partial y}{\partial b}\frac{\partial b}{\partial u}\frac{du}{dr} + \frac{\partial y}{\partial b}\frac{\partial b}{\partial v}\frac{dv}{dr}
\end{align*}
$$

Comment: You're leaving us with nothing to answer. Seems correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the community, it has been verified as correct.